# convert an negative integer to 32bit binary in python

Tags: python

I would like to create a function which gives the following things

```
32_bit_binary(-1) should be '11111111111111111111111111111111'
32_bit_binary(1) should be  '00000000000000000000000000000001'
```

Now I gave the following code

```
def 32_bit_binary(num_bits):
return '{:032b}'.format(num_bits)
```

But when I gave this

```
print(32_bit_binary(-1))
```

it came -00000000000000000000000000000001

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @gspr said, formatting as base 2 doesn’t give you the actual representation. You can solve it by masking the negative integer, which has infinitely many leading 1s for the purposes of bitwise operations, down to 32 bits:

```
return f"{num_bits & 0xffff_ffff:032b}"
```

Answer (score 1):

String formatting like `{:032b}` does not give you the actual *representation* of the number. It just writes the number in base-2. That's a purely mathematical operation. Implementation details like how the computer *represents* said number (like using binary, using 2's complement for negative numbers, etc.) are not in the scope of those string formatting operations.

A good way to get at the actual representations of values in Python is the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. For example, `struct.pack("@i", -1)` returns the bytestring `b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'`. Printing that bytestring in binary is left as an exercise to the reader.

PS: For numbers other than `-1`, you may be surprised by the output of `struct.pack`. The term you'll want to look up is *endianness*, and the `@` in my `struct.pack` formatting string.